# Dynamic Script for Column Comparison between two table in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have two tables with 28 columns in them. In the production environment, SQL Server collation is set as case sensitivity.

I have to check the value like as:

```
UPPER(Target.SKU) <> UPPER(Source.SKU)
   OR UPPER(Target.PRC) <> UPPER(Source.PRC)
   OR UPPER(Target.PACKSIZE) <> UPPER(Source.PACKSIZE).
```

Is it possible to do it dynamically, without repeating the `UPPER` statement
for each column?

I am just trying to do it more neatly. Please share your thoughts.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do two things: 
First, before going through line by line, check if the both tables have the same content

```
SELECT CHECKSUM_AGG(BINARY_CHECKSUM(*))
FROM target_table

SELECT CHECKSUM_AGG(BINARY_CHECKSUM(*))
FROM source_table
```

If these numbers match, you have a very, very high probability the content of both tables is identical.

If the numbers don't match, check row by row to find the different records:

```
;with cte1 AS (
SELECT t.id, BINARY_CHECKSUM(*) AS checker
FROM target_table t
)

;with cte2 AS (
SELECT s.id, BINARY_CHECKSUM(*) AS checker
FROM source_table s
)

SELECT cte1.id, cte2.id
FROM cte1 
INNER JOIN cte2
ON cte1.id = cte2.id
AND cte1.checker <> cte2.checker
```

This should return the specific records in your table that do not match in both tables.

Comment: Thanks, but i am implementing this check inside merge.

Answer (score 0):

If you have other logic in your statement you could do a sub select with that logic first and select the fields as UPPER then do the comparrison

```
select fields 
FROM (
Select UPPER(SKU), UPPER(PRC), UPPER(PACKETSIZE), otherfields
from table
where logic
)
WHERE Target. SKU <>  Source. SKU
OR  Target. PRC <> Source. PRC
OR  Target. PACKSIZE <>  Source. PACKSIZE
```